# tikz-cd not working when using package babel (spanish)

Tags: babel, tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

I'm trying to make a commutative diagram while using the spanish babel package but I'm encountering some problems.

I've made two MWE; one that doesn't work and one that does:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzcd}
   G \arrow[d, "\varepsilon"', two heads] \arrow[r, "\varphi"] & H \\
   G/N \arrow[ru, "\varphi"', dashed]                          &  
   \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

and

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzcd}
   G \arrow[d, "\varepsilon"', two heads] \arrow[r, "\varphi"] & H \\
   G/N \arrow[ru, "\varphi"', dashed]                          &  
   \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

The **former fails** to work while the **latter works** just fine. *The only difference being the spanish babel package*. I really need to use both the package and the tikz-cd environment. Is there a way of doing so?

Here is a picture of the desired output (which is the result of the second piece of code). I want this while having the spanish babel package loaded.

[image: commutative diagram]

Edit: I just noticed that if I remove the names of the arrows (\varepsilon and \varphi) then it compiles just fine (I want to have those though).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spanish `babel` makes `"` into an active character which kills `\arrow[d, "\varepsilon"', two heads]`

As this is quite common there is a `tikz` library to fix is, just add

```
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
```

after loading `tikz-cd` and the example compiles again

Answer (score 1):

First, daleif's answer is the right way to do this.
Then, this is a case in which the alternative syntax in the [tikz-cd manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd) could be useful:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzcd}
   G\arrow[two heads]{d}[swap]{\varepsilon}\arrow{r}{\varphi} & H\\
   G/N\arrow[dashed]{ru}[swap]{\varphi}
   \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Produces:

[image]

as expected